# What's the closed form of $f(x) := \inf \{ \frac{1}{3r} |y-x|^{3} + |y| \; \big| \; y \in R \}$?

Tags: calculus, polynomials, optimization

Let $f: R \to R$ be defined by $f(x) := \inf \{ \frac{1}{3r} |y-x|^{3} + |y| \; \big| \; y \in R  \}$ where $r > o$. What is the explicit formula of $f(x)$ in terms of $x$?

It seems $f$ is a piecewise function, but the numbers of pieces are a lot.

---

Edit:
The motivation for this question is I wanted to see if $\ell_3$-norm  could be a better approximation for the epigraph of nonsmooth convex functions compared to $\ell_2$-norm. So I used the example $\|x\|_{1}$.

For those who downvoted questions or voted for closing this question: There is a high probability that you have no idea what I said as the motivation. However, all one needs to solve this question is calculus 1. I thought calc students might be interested in solving it. Just be aware that sometimes writing extra things, motivations, and details will cut the audience off. I was trying to write down a question that can be seen by a large audience, not just people familiar with the *Moreau Envelope*.

Comment: Before voting down, care to comment!

Comment: I didn't down-vote, but I suspect it's to do with there being a lack of demonstrated effort in the question. Without the final line, it would be a PSQ. Right now, there is a vote to close for reason "Missing context or other details".

Comment: As for your problem, for any given $x$, $\frac{1}{3r}|y - x|^3 + |y|$ is a sum of coercive convex functions in $y$, achieving minima at $y = x$ and $y = 0$ respectively. This infimum should be a minimum, achieved somewhere in between. So, I'd say that two cases are necessary: $x \ge 0$ and $x < 0$, and both reduce to finding a local minimum of a cubic, which should be simple calculus.

Comment: @TheoBendit Thanks for your comment. I would say cases like $|x| \leq \sqrt{r}$ , $|x| \geq \sqrt{r}$ need to be considered.

Comment: @TheoBendit  Regarding the downvoting, given that I myself contributed a lot in answering questions, I know that some questions are straightforward and do not need any more details or effort. Is my question unclear? The reason "Missing context or other details" is ridiculous!   The better reason although stupid one would be "this question is short"
Let's say someone does not even know where to start in solving the question; thus, no effort is available, does that mean he/she has no right to write a question?

Comment: You can find plenty of arguments on meta about this close reason (look for the tag [low-quality-posts](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/low-quality-posts)) that go over these arguments in detail. I agree that not every question needs to be held to this same standard, and sometimes this context serves to clutter a question more than is necessary. However, I do think this particular question could use more. (cont.)

Comment: I am generally supportive of encouraging (less so about legislating) people to include context in their questions. One (IMHO) good reason is to know to whom I'm pitching the answer. While I've been a little familiar with you and your interests for a while, other answerers may not know what level you're at. You might be a middling calculus/analysis student who only knows convexity by the name "concave up". For example, I know I can drop a word like "coercive" and trust you know what it means, but this is not clear to others from your post.

Comment: I do see what you mean about $\sqrt{r}$, by the way. You could weasel around it by using a maximum formula, to keep it down to these two cases. This is far from unmanageable. The last function I had to define had $10$ cases, *after* I cut the cases down with absolute values and maximum formulas!

Comment: @TheoBendit,  I edited the question. I'm not interested anymore to write down answers to questions in this community.  (At least for a while)

Comment: I get: $f(x)$ is even with $f(0) = 0$. And $$f(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
 x - \frac23\sqrt r & x > \sqrt r \\[6pt]
 \frac{1}{3r}x^3 & 0 \le x \le \sqrt r. 
\end{array}
\right.$$